# How can I set checkbox to checked in a datatable column when a master checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, dynamic, datatable

I have a datatable for class attendance that is comprised of a student name and 4 columns of checkboxes per row.  The Select All column is for the user to dynamically set checked/unchecked attribute for the remaining checkboxes in the row.  Ultimately, the form will be saved and the database updated with the value of the checkboxes. When the form is presented, the database does not contain a record of what is presented to the user, it will be inserted when the form is saved.

```
Select All  Student Name    On Time  Present  Contributing  Prep Lesson 
     x      Mickey Mouse        o       o          o            o
```

HTML:

```
<table id="UserTable" class="table table-bordered"> 
    <thead>
      <th style="text-align:center;">Select All</th>
      <th style="text-align:center;">Student Name</th>
      <th style="text-align:center;">On Time</th>
      <th style="text-align:center;">Present</th>
      <th style="text-align:center;">Contributing</th>
      <th style="text-align:center;">Prep. Lesson</th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <?php if(!empty($students)) { ?>
        <?php foreach($students as $student) { ?>
          <tr>
            <div class="container content">
              <!-- select all -->
              <td style="text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" id="select-all" onchange="selectAll(this)"></td>
              <!-- student -->
              <td class="student-name"><?php echo $student['first_name'] . ' ' . $student['last_name'] ?></td>
              <!-- on-time -->
              <td class="on-time" style="text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" id="on-time"></td>
              <!-- Present -->
              <td class="present" style="text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" id="present"></td>
              <!-- contributing -->
              <td class="contribute" style="text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" id="contribute"></td>
              <!-- prepared lesson -->
              <td class="prep-lesson" style="text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" id="prep-lesson"></td>            
          </tr>  
      <?php }} ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
Attempts at Javascript code which do not work:
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#UserTable').DataTable();
      });

      $('#UserTable tbody').on( 'click', 'tr td:eq(0)', function () {
        //var onTime = $(this).parents('#userTable tbody").siblings('#on-time');         
        //$(onTime).attr('checked', true);
        alert("col1");
      });

      function selectAll(elem) {
        alert('in onChange');
        var table = $('#UserTable').DataTable();
        if(elem.checked) {
          // var onTime = $(this).parents('#userTable tbody').siblings('.on-time');     
          // var colData = table.column(this).data();          
          // $(onTime).attr('checked', true);

          alert('checked');
        }
        else {
          alert ('unchecked');
        }
      }
</script>
```

```
Thanks for your help,
Dennis
```

Comment: First thin I notice is that you are using a static `id` attribute in a for loop. IDs need to be unique. Also, in your JavaScript code `elem` in undefined…

Comment: Beware also that when working with Check-all checkboxes, you should correctly apply their [`indeterminate` state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#indeterminate_state_checkboxes), if they dependent checkboxes are not all checked. Do you want to have that in the answer as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a group with a “check all” checkbox, the grouping checkbox should also update dependent on the other checkboxes’ states. So after checking “check all“ and removing one dependent check, it should represent that [indeterminate state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#indeterminate_state_checkboxes).

So the suggestion here does the following:

- Establish groups of checkboxes by iterating on `<tr>` elements
- Extract the first checkbox found inside as the grouping checkbox
- Update dependent checkboxes if the grouping one changes state by binding to [the `change' event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)
- And update the grouping checkbox if one of the dependent boxes change state

  - Filter the list of checkboxes to find those that are checked with [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
  - Count the checked checkboxes
  - Uncheck grouping box if 0 dependent boxes are checked
  - Check if all dependent boxes are checked
  - Set indeterminate state for any other case

Key to this solution is that by binding event listeners from the NodeList allows easily grouping the checkboxes. Using `onclick="listener"` would render that difficult.

Also it’s using the [`change` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event), as you should always use events that are data-oriented and not interaction-oriented. Users could use the keyboard or other means to change a checkboxe’s state.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr').forEach(tr => {
  // all the variables inside here are valid for one tr, establishing a checkbox group
  const [checkAll, ...checkboxes] = tr.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

  // propagate checked state down to dependent checkboxes
  // we simply copy the grouping boxes’ state to the dependent boxes
  checkAll.addEventListener('change', e => checkboxes.forEach(c => c.checked = e.currentTarget.checked));

  // propagate checked state up depending on group state
  checkboxes.forEach(c => c.addEventListener('change', e => {
    // list all checked dependent checkboxes
    const checked = checkboxes.filter(cb => cb.checked);

    // and compare count with the whole group
    if (checked.length === checkboxes.length) {
      // all are checked
      checkAll.checked = true;
      checkAll.indeterminate = false;
    } else if (checked.length === 0) {
      // none is checked
      checkAll.checked = false;
      checkAll.indeterminate = false;
    } else {
      // some are checked
      checkAll.indeterminate = true;
    }
  }));
});
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align:center;">Select All</th>
      <th style="text-align:center;">Student Name</th>
      <th style="text-align:center;">On Time</th>
      <th style="text-align:center;">Present</th>
      <th style="text-align:center;">Contributing</th>
      <th style="text-align:center;">Prep. Lesson</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <div class="container content">
        <!-- select all -->
        <td style="text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" aria-label="Check all criteria for Mickey Mouse"></td>
        <!-- student -->
        <td class="student-name">
          Mickey Mouse
        </td>
        <!-- on-time -->
        <td class="on-time" style="text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" id="on-time"></td>
        <!-- Present -->
        <td class="present" style="text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" id="present"></td>
        <!-- contributing -->
        <td class="contribute" style="text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" id="contribute"></td>
        <!-- prepared lesson -->
        <td class="prep-lesson" style="text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" id="prep-lesson"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <div class="container content">
        <!-- select all -->
        <td style="text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" aria-label="Check all criteria for Mini Mouse"></td>
        <!-- student -->
        <td class="student-name">
          Mini Mouse
        </td>
        <!-- on-time -->
        <td class="on-time" style="text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" id="on-time"></td>
        <!-- Present -->
        <td class="present" style="text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" id="present"></td>
        <!-- contributing -->
        <td class="contribute" style="text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" id="contribute"></td>
        <!-- prepared lesson -->
        <td class="prep-lesson" style="text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" id="prep-lesson"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

### Other Improvements

The code included an `id="select-all"` inside a for loop. This is invalid, as IDs need to be unique. I removed it, because the suggested solution doesn’t need any IDs.

I also added a specific label for the first checkbox, to be sure. Assistive technology is often able to determine the labels for inputs inside a table from the table structure.

```
    <td style="text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" aria-label="Check all criteria for Mickey Mouse"></td>
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, how do I implement the javascript document.querySelectorAll, in the $(document).ready(function() ?  I have an inklng to what your doing, but not a complete understanding.  The event listener is setup to fire when the select all checkbox is checked or unchecked?

Comment: I oversaw that you were looking for a jQuery solution. If that’s important to you, maybe you can add the tag? You simply put the whole code inside your ready function. I’ll try to be more precise in the answer.

Comment: So, I added some more comments and links to the docs. Also, I removed the reduce function for the much simpler filter function. That should make the code more understandable.

Comment: Andy, still confused about what to put in the javascript <script> tag at end of page.  I added a document ready function and added the javascript code you provided.  It works for your example, but not on my form.  I get an error:  jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addEventListener')
    at 4:735:20
    at NodeList.forEach (<anonymous>)   Do I need to use jQuery?  if so, how would I implement that?  I can't see the source for the run code snippet example.

Comment: Andy, thank you so much for this solution.  I couldn't even grasp it conceptually.  I  would rate myself a novice to intermediate web developer having moved from App development in Windows.  I was able to view the source for your snippet and found out how you were using it in the script tag.  It's working for me perfectly!

Comment: Andy, I have a follow-up question.  I added a second table to the page and this broke the select/unselect all code you provided.  As near as I can determine, the code does not specify any particular <table> so when it runs I get a "cannot read properties of undefiined" error.  If I comment out my new <table>, then the code runs perfectly.

Comment: Andy, I have a follow-up question.  I added a second table to the page that does not contain any checkboxes and this broke the select/unselect all code you provided.  I made sure that the table ids are different.  As near as I can determine, the code does not specify any particular <table> so when it runs I get a "cannot read properties of undefined" error.  If I comment out my new <table>, then the code runs perfectly.  Is there any way I can specify a table in the code so it only runs on the table with the checkboxes?

Comment: I got it!  Can't believe I figured it out, but the original code you provided was a learning moment for me.  I added the table id and it worked...   document.querySelectorAll('#UserTable tbody tr').forEach(tr => {

Comment: I’m glad you’re advancing!